# Scaling multiple surfaces with variable width results in incorrect position

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having trouble fixing how I scale an 'attack' animation. Due to the attack being scaled the same as the walk the `player` position changes because it is double the width of standard images, resulting in an incorrect position.

The step-by-step process that the 2 examples below go through:

1. Load image
2. Scale image IMPORTANT: (x, y, width height)
3. Add image to the animation list

This is how I would add an image that is `16x32`

```py
for index, array in enumerate(self.walking_positions):
    for n in self.walking_positions[index]:
        scaled = (scale_normal(n, 3)[0], scale_normal(n, 3)[1], n[2] * 3, n[3] * 3)
        image = image_at(self.spritesheet, scaled)
        self.walking[index].append(image)
    self.idle[index].append(self.walking_positions[index][0])
```

However, I do it in the same way for images that are `32x32`

```py
for index, array in enumerate(self.slash_animation):
    for n in self.slash_animation[index]:
        scaled = (scale_normal(n, 3)[0], scale_normal(n, 3)[1], n[2] * 3, n[3] * 3)
        image = image_at(self.spritesheet, scaled)
        self.slashing[index].append(image)
```

In the [video below](https://streamable.com/e/cnnu8u), you can see `pygame.Rect` of the walking surface and `pygame.Rect` of the attack surface. The difference is that the attacking width is doubled.
It's not an issue with `player.pos`. When looking at the console I found the following.
This is `player.pos` when both not attacking and attacking: `[632, 392.03]`

[Video of issue](https://streamable.com/e/cnnu8u)

[Snapshot of sprite sheet (with grid example)](https://ibb.co/vVHVNk7)

Comment: Are you going to use ```pygame.transform.scale``` for scaling? Does it not distort your images especially when the images have different width and heights?

Comment: Currently, I am scaling with `pygame.transform.scale`.  I was wondering how I could rectify the position to be static. I want the position to be invariable of the size.

Comment: *"It's not an issue with player.pos"* - However it is not an issue with the scaling either. Is the player's position accidentally applied twice when attacking?

Comment: I've checked that that's not the case. I've also put a conditional that detects if attacking is true so that position is not set twice.

Comment: The problem is not caused by the code in the question. The bug is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Well, here's the github link if you'd like to take a look: https://github.com/JoshuaDRose/topdown-rpg/tree/master/src

Comment: No, I don't want to look at that, way too much code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why `self.rect.centery = self.pos.y` only when `self.do_movement` is `False`? `self.rect` should always be set. I suspect the problem is somewhere in `Player.update`. I suggest `print(self.rect.topleft)` in `Player.update`. `pos` is irrelevant the player is drawn at the position stored in the `rect` attribute.

Comment: I even managed to run your game, but I can't reproduce the issue. Have you commited all the code?

Comment: yep, the issue has been solved by removing the rect declaration. This is not really a 'solve' or a fix, because i'd like to keep the rect, even when doing an animation like attacking. The new issue is in the issues tab of the repository link

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but only intended to give you some idea.

I have used `pygame.transform.scale` but somehow it distorts some of the images. My alternative approach was rather arduous. In every image, I defined additional information like offsets and hitboxes. So if I have 10 images for an animation, I also add 10 sets of offsets and hitboxes (*although I have a function to handle None values so I only need to define the offsets and hitboxes when necessary*).

My offsets come in tuple (left, top) which is the left and top offsets of surface rect when blit to screen. My hitboxes come in tuple (left, top, width, height) which is not an issue when blitting to screen but may be an issue when it comes to collision detection

```
animations = {
    "pre-slide": {
        "images": [{"image": f"assets/images/S{x}.png"} for x in range(1, 2)],
        "offsets": [(0, 9)],
        "hitboxes": [(0, 0, 32, 48)],
    },
    "slide": {
        "images": [{"image": f"assets/images/S{x}.png"} for x in range(2, 3)],
        "offsets": [(0, 24)],
        "hitboxes": [(0, 0, 57, 33)],
    }
}
```

And then I redefine the position as follows where self.offset (*object property*) retrieves the offset tuple depending on which image is currently being used.

```
def update_position(self, x: float, y: float):
    _x, _y = self.offset
    self.rect.x = x + _x
    self.rect.y = y + _y
```

Where `x = self.rect.x + self.dx` and `y = self.rect.y + self.dy`; and where self.dx and self.dy are the object displacements after moving and/or tile collision.

Comment: Thank you for your submission. Currently, I am doing the same thing where I am applying an offset to the position, saving the previous position, and then once the animation is done, returning to that original saved position. Although this is not ideal, it's my best option.

Comment: @JoshuaRose I have also thought of another solution, and that is to edit the images themselves, have them the same widths and heights, and correctly position them so the animation becomes smooth. But this too is more arduous. Moreover, adding more player actions/images brings more work with this approach.

Comment: Brillian idea, and as much as that would be a life saver, the problem here, (more visible in the sprite sheet image) is that the attack animation would not fit in the regular walk animation as its width is too big, and therefore is centered between a 32x32 tile

Comment: That problem can still be resolved by extending the widths and heights further, enough for the walk and attack animation to coincide while the weapon now being at the extended space. The problem I can think of here is that the hitbox will now become bigger, unless you specify the hitboxes smaller in the code or you use point-to-point-distance instead of pygame colliderect for collision detection.

Comment: Among the list of possible errors, an issue with the hitbox is of paramount severity. Therefore I think rectifying the position vector might be the best option

Comment: True. Moreover, editing images for a project is only good for that project. Having a code to rectify the positions and is reusable to other projects sounds better IMO.

Comment: I completely agree. Solutions that apply to anything are always the best.